# How to calculate datetime difference using Django and python

Tags: python, django, datetime

I need some help. I need to calculate datetime difference by matching with DB `date` field value. Here I am getting some error. I am explaining the error below.

> Error:

```
expected string or buffer
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginsave/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
expected string or buffer
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py in parse_datetime, line 94
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
pers = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
if int(cnt) == 3:
    pers.status = 1;
    pers.date = datetime.now
    pers.save()
else:
    cnt1 = int(cnt)+1
    pers.count = cnt1
    pers.save()
```

Here I am getting error inside the `if statement`. Here I am storing the datetime inside the db. Here I need to calculate the difference with todays datetime value and the difference should be in hours(`i.e-1hrs,2hrs...`). Please help.

Comment: what is cnt in the if statement?

Comment: I have calculated it before. its 1/2/3.

Comment: with what date do you want to make the difference?? todays datetime and what?

Comment: and that saved db datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `pers.date` is a datetime field. (By seeing your error, I think this is a CharField, Recommend you change to DatetimeField)

Then you should do `pers.date = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)`

For timedelta, you can use dateutil package. If you want to calculate via tradtional timedelta object, you can do like below:

```
td = pers.date-datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
ts = td.total_seconds()
total_hours = ts/3600
print int(total_hours), "ago"
```

Comment: THen how to calculate difference in hrs.

Comment: I used your code but it throws this `Exception Value: 
can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes` error.

Comment: In my case I am getting the DB date is like `2017-06-29 06:14:14.446676+00:00` and the todays datetime value is `2017-06-29 06:29:52.568665`.

Comment: Becuase django save the datetime field with timezone, you need to bring both value into same timezone or add `datetime.utcnow()` instead `now()`

Comment: Updated the answer. But I'd strongly recommend to understand first before copy paste code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147890/discussion-between-subhra-and-swagat).

Answer (score 1):

If you have imported datetime like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
pers.date = datetime.now()
```

else if you imported like this:

```
import datetime
pers.date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

To get the date difference, you can subtract two dates:

```
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 11, 37, 26, 517124)
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 29, 12, 37, 26, 517124) # 1 hour difference
>>> (d2 - d1).total_seconds()/60/60
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''' Python 3.6 '''
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

''' date_in_question is a tz-aware datetime '''

A_YEAR = timedelta(days=365)

if datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - date_in_question >= A_YEAR:
    pass     # Expired
else:
    pass     # Still edible
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to indent code to format it correctly (or press the `{}` icon)